# Plotting a non-linear graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have this equation `f(g)=1+cos(g)*cosh(g)-a*g*(cos(g)*sinh(g)-sin(g)*cosh(g))=0`. I am trying to plot it for `(a,g)`.

I have the initial condition that when `a=0` then `g=1.8751`.

I am not sure how to code it as an equation with two unknowns and two initial values ?

My suggestion would be to plot the graph by using the solve function by using `a=a+da` (where `da` is small increment of `a`) and using the previous value of `g` as an initial value to find `g` for the new value of `a`.

Comment: Why not just using `ezplot('1+cos(g)*cosh(g)-a*g*(cos(g)*sinh(g)-sin(g)*cosh(g))')` ?

Comment: @AVK hmm...that didn't work.It would would work if I only want to plot the first part of the function '1+cos(g)*cosh(g)' but with the function I have there are two variables..